# jQuery scroll to a section and stick before continued scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, easing

Not really sure what this feature is called, but it probably uses jQuery's easing features.  [This site](http://sagacify.com/) does a really good job of it.  Basically, it auto scrolls to the the next section and sticks so you can only view one part at a time.  I have the section height part taken care of, but I'm clueless on how to call the easing.  All the research I've done only relates to sticky headers and sidebars.  I'm not even sure what this feature is called!

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y2uTv/1/

Here's what my JS currently looks like:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $(.section).css(height, windowHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing jQuery's CSS method the variable you declared. Remove the quotes around `'windowHeight'` and it should work right away.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('div.section').css('height', windowHeight);
});                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                   remove quotes
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ax8XZ/1/

---

I can give you a basic idea on how you should implement what you want

With your issue, you going to need differently named `div`s, you'll have to single out each `section` somehow. Adding an `id` attribute is probably the easiest.

Next, you'll need to add an event with `scroll()` that moves to the `top` of the next div, whether it be up or down to either snap the window to that position, or `animate()` to it.

You'll need some way to track the current positioned `section` so you can know where to move next during the `scroll()` event.

Comment: It's updated, but that still doesn't help me with the sticky issue.